# What Welcome Message would you give a new user?

Tags: discussion

I have been contemplating posting a welcome message to new users, in the comments of their question or answer.  Ideally it would stay there for a few days, a week at most, then be deleted.  Currently we don't have enough traffic for this to be a significant body of work. I [previously mentioned something similar and did not get any volunteers](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2102) so I plan on managing it myself.

A comment can be 600 characters, so that the longest it could be.  I think the audience would be any new user with a first post and less then 100 rep (*excludes people with other SE accounts and experience*).

If you have suggestion for a new user welcome message, please post it as an answer.  It should include links to anything you think is important for new users to read.

Answer (score 2):

**580 of 600 characters with links**

Welcome to Pets.SE.  We are a question and answer site, possibly a bit different then other places you may have visited.  You can learn more about us at [our help center](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help), if you have questions about how things work you can ask in [Meta.](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/) We call our chat room [The Litter Box](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964), you can post there once you have [gained 20 reputation.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) I personally am not a big chatter, but I do peek in and say 'hi' once in a while.

Comment: I would recommend against hitting new users with a bunch of links all at once; pick the one or two things that are most important for the situation at hand.  I usually link to the tour ("[tour]" is a magic shortcut in comments), and might use "[edit]" if I'm asking for improvements or link to something specific in the help center (on-topic list, what comments are for, etc, depending on the situation).

Comment: Err, those magic links were meant to be in square brackets, but comment markdown parsed them for me.  Oops; don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I'd really like to add "if you have a medical emergency, don't wait for us -- _call a vet now_".